# Why use '{' and '}' to define a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation to understand why the `{` and `}` characters are wrapped around variables on some examples I've seen.  Can anyone example why we would do that?

For example:

```
const {app} = require('./app/app.js');
```

Comment: I suggest to read about *destructuring assignment* in ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: [MDN - Destructuizing Assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Destructuring assignments!  Now I know.  Thank you.